# Does linux "gdb a.out param1 param2" pass param1 and 2 to "gdb" or "a.out"?

Tags: linux, parsing, parameters, gdb

Is there any case that param1 and param2 are passed to gdb, and some cases passed to a.out, and some cases, 1 for each?

How does linux shell parse and decide which param for which program?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does linux shell parse and decide which param for which program?

Linux shell simply passes all params to gdb. It's gdb which decides how to interpret these params.

When you invoke gdb like `gdb a.out param1 param2` you want to debug program `a.out` either loading core dump `param1` or attaching to pid `param1`. See [Invoking gdb doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Invoking-GDB.html).

If you want to pass params to a program you should use `--args` gdb option. For example this will pass `param1`, `param2` to a program:

```
gdb --args a.out param1 param2
(gdb) run
```

Alternatively:

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) run param1 param2
```